# Insert byte at location 0 and right shift the remaining data bits

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, iso8583

I am really struggling to complete this piece, any thoughts or pointers will help me a lot. Here is my problem:

1. I am working on [ISO 8583](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8583) layer and data element 32 is defined as n ..11, which means the element is numeric, variable length with max size 11.
2. and this need to be sent in binary format (not ASCII).
3. We need to show LLNN, ex ISO binary raw should look like this : 11 06 01 04 00 00 00

Till now I was able to complete fill the byte[] array with (11/2)+(11%2) size of 6 with BCD(06 01 04 00 00 00). and I got the total length of the field calculated as 11, Now I need to insert this at byte[0] with the 11 not 0B i.e 0001 0001 packed to one byte `byte[]`as 11 , my logic as shown below when I give nBytes=1(first 255 chars in BCD ISO) it will insert the length field value as either 0b 01 04 00 00 00 or if i pass nBytes as 2, its giving 00 0b 04 00 00 00. Something going wrong with the right shift logic...

Can somebody help me and correct this below logic to bring the results as 11 06 01 04 00 00 00

```
int nBytes=1;
for (int i = nBytes - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    buf[i] = (byte)(length & 0xFF);
    length >>= 8;
}
outstream.write(buf);
```

Comment: Why are you bit shifting at all?  Can't you just create the bytes that you need to send a ISO 8583 message?  Add a byte that contains 11 hex or 17 decimal and prepend it to your other bytes.

Comment: @Gilbert:Thanks for getting back Gilbert, I can, thought to avoid the multiple array object creations...if right shift can taken care then that would be greate...I have implemented solution based on your input...just checking on the host side to see will it decode properly...I will update you soon how this new fix went..

Comment: @Gilbert: 17 decimal way worked perfectly on ISO system....Thanks for the thought..

Comment: Can you please explain  `11 06 01 04 00 00 00`? And wat ismeant by `(11/2)+(11%2)`?, also what is the meaning of nBytes? Additionally, what is the content of buf[] beforehand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally ended up using the two byte array objects. One holding the original request and calculating the length of the field in decimal and putting it in the first location i.e. 0 index of the secondary byte array and appending the original byte array to this.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this function](http://ideone.com/2A0cCB) performs the BCD conversion you are looking for:

```
class T {
    public static byte toBCD(int n)
    {
        // a*10 + b -> a*16 + b;
        byte a = (byte)(n / 10);
        byte b = (byte)(n % 10);

        return (byte) (a * 0x10 + b);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        assert(toBCD(11) == 0x11);
        assert(toBCD(28) == 0x28);
    }
}
```